# Add image inside body with autoTable library

Tags: jspdf-autotable

> I try to add image inside body show [object object]
> Please anyone can help

```
pdf.autoTable({
  startY: rowY,
  body: [
    [
      { content: "", styles: { cellWidth: 5 } },
      {
        image: user.image,
        width: 30,
        colSpan: 2,
      },
    ],
  ],
});
```

Comment: please provide the value for user.image

Comment: const user = [{image: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/logo.jpeg"}]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your user variable is an array which means you are accessing it wrong.

```
pdf.autoTable({
  startY: rowY,
  body: [
    [
      { content: "", styles: { cellWidth: 5 } },
      {
        image: user[0].image,
        width: 30,
        colSpan: 2,
      },
    ],
  ],
});
```